# Add missing dates to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, date, plot, pandas, dataframe

My data can have multiple events on a given date or NO events on a date. I take these events, get a count by date and plot them.  However, when I plot them, my two series don't always match.

```
idx = pd.date_range(df['simpleDate'].min(), df['simpleDate'].max())
s = df.groupby(['simpleDate']).size()
```

In the above code **idx** becomes a range of say 30 dates. 09-01-2013 to 09-30-2013
However **S** may only have 25 or 26 days because no events happened for a given date. I then get an AssertionError as the sizes dont match when I try to plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
ax.bar(idx.to_pydatetime(), s, color='green')
```

What's the proper way to tackle this? Do I want to remove dates with no values from **IDX** or (which I'd rather do) is add to the series the missing date with a count of 0. I'd rather have a full graph of 30 days with 0 values. If this approach is right, any suggestions on how to get started? Do I need some sort of dynamic `reindex` function?

Here's a snippet of **S** ( `df.groupby(['simpleDate']).size()`  ), notice no entries for 04 and 05.

```
09-02-2013     2
09-03-2013    10
09-06-2013     5
09-07-2013     1
```

Answer (score 417, accepted):

You could use `Series.reindex`:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range('09-01-2013', '09-30-2013')

s = pd.Series({'09-02-2013': 2,
               '09-03-2013': 10,
               '09-06-2013': 5,
               '09-07-2013': 1})
s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)

s = s.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
print(s)
```

yields

```
2013-09-01     0
2013-09-02     2
2013-09-03    10
2013-09-04     0
2013-09-05     0
2013-09-06     5
2013-09-07     1
2013-09-08     0
...
```

Comment: `reindex` is an amazing function. It can (1) reorder existing data to match a new set of labels, (2) insert new rows where no label previously existed, (3) fill data for missing labels, (including by forward/backward filling) (4) select rows by label!

Comment: @unutbu This answers part of a question I had too, thanks! But was wondering if you knew how to dynamically create a list of with the dates which have events?

Comment: There is one problem (or bug) with reindex though: it doesn't work with dates before 1/1/1970, so in this case df.resample() works perfectly.

Comment: you may use this instead for idx to skip entering start and end dates manually: `idx = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())`

Comment: Dropping the link to the documentation here, to save you the search: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Comment: is there a way to keep the index's name when running this function?

Comment: for `df.reindex` with multiple index levels you can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286882/how-to-reindex-a-multiindex-dataframe

Comment: is it possible to add the 'interpolation' method while doing this?

Comment: reindex does not work at least anymore

Answer (score 96):

A quicker workaround is to use [`.asfreq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html).  This doesn't require creation of a new index to call within `.reindex()`.

```
# "broken" (staggered) dates
dates = pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2012-05-01'), 
                  pd.Timestamp('2012-05-04'), 
                  pd.Timestamp('2012-05-06')])
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dates)

print(s.asfreq('D'))
2012-05-01    1.0
2012-05-02    NaN
2012-05-03    NaN
2012-05-04    2.0
2012-05-05    NaN
2012-05-06    3.0
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I really prefer this method; you avoid having to call `date_range` since it implicitly uses the first and last index as the start and end (which is what you would almost always want).

Comment: Very clean and professional method. Works well with using interpolate afterwards as well.

Comment: I second this. This is also a great method to use before merging two dataframes of different index length where joins, merges etc. almost always leads to errors such as a column full of NaNs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still have a question. Given that I want to start on date x-x-x and end on date y-y-y and on my dataset 's' I have dates e-e-e to f-f-f, that are between dates x-x-x and y-y-y. Using  "asfreq" how can I fill the dates on my dataset 's' from x-x-x to y-y-y? I have not found on the docs. Thank you

Comment: Yes I used this method to insert NaN in missing dates in a dataframe before plotting it with matplatlib

Answer (score 38):

An alternative approach is [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), which can handle duplicate dates in addition to missing dates.  For example:

```
df.resample('D').mean()
```

`resample` is a deferred operation like `groupby` so you need to follow it with another operation.  In this case `mean` works well, but you can also use many other pandas methods like `max`, `sum`, etc.

Here is the original data, but with an extra entry for '2013-09-03':

```
             val
date           
2013-09-02     2
2013-09-03    10
2013-09-03    20    <- duplicate date added to OP's data
2013-09-06     5
2013-09-07     1
```

And here are the results:

```
             val
date            
2013-09-02   2.0
2013-09-03  15.0    <- mean of original values for 2013-09-03
2013-09-04   NaN    <- NaN b/c date not present in orig
2013-09-05   NaN    <- NaN b/c date not present in orig
2013-09-06   5.0
2013-09-07   1.0
```

I left the missing dates as NaNs to make it clear how this works, but you can add `fillna(0)` to replace NaNs with zeroes as requested by the OP or alternatively use something like `interpolate()` to fill with non-zero values based on the neighboring rows.

Answer (score 37):

One issue is that `reindex` will fail if there are duplicate values. Say we're working with timestamped data, which we want to index by date:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamps': pd.to_datetime(
        ['2016-11-15 1:00','2016-11-16 2:00','2016-11-16 3:00','2016-11-18 4:00']),
    'values':['a','b','c','d']})
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamps']).floor('D')
df
```

yields

```
            timestamps             values
2016-11-15  "2016-11-15 01:00:00"  a
2016-11-16  "2016-11-16 02:00:00"  b
2016-11-16  "2016-11-16 03:00:00"  c
2016-11-18  "2016-11-18 04:00:00"  d
```

Due to the duplicate `2016-11-16` date, an attempt to reindex:

```
all_days = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='D')
df.reindex(all_days)
```

fails with:

```
...
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

(by this it means the index has duplicates, not that it is itself a dup)

Instead, we can use `.loc` to look up entries for all dates in range:

```
df.loc[all_days]
```

yields

```
            timestamps             values
2016-11-15  "2016-11-15 01:00:00"  a
2016-11-16  "2016-11-16 02:00:00"  b
2016-11-16  "2016-11-16 03:00:00"  c
2016-11-17  NaN                    NaN
2016-11-18  "2016-11-18 04:00:00"  d
```

`fillna` can be used on the column series to fill blanks if needed.

Comment: Any idea on what to do if Date column contains `Blanks` or `NULLS`? `df.loc[all_days]` won't work in that case.

Comment: Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike

Answer (score 10):

Here's a nice method to fill in missing dates into a dataframe, with your choice of `fill_value`, `days_back` to fill in, and sort order (`date_order`) by which to sort the dataframe:

```
def fill_in_missing_dates(df, date_col_name = 'date',date_order = 'asc', fill_value = 0, days_back = 30):

    df.set_index(date_col_name,drop=True,inplace=True)
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
    d = datetime.now().date()
    d2 = d - timedelta(days = days_back)
    idx = pd.date_range(d2, d, freq = "D")
    df = df.reindex(idx,fill_value=fill_value)
    df[date_col_name] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)

    return df
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always just use `DataFrame.merge()` utilizing a left join from an 'All Dates' DataFrame to the 'Missing Dates' DataFrame. Example below.

```py
# example DataFrame with missing dates between min(date) and max(date)
missing_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.to_datetime([
        '2022-02-10'
        ,'2022-02-11'
        ,'2022-02-14'
        ,'2022-02-14'
        ,'2022-02-24'
        ,'2022-02-16'
    ])
    ,'value':[10,20,5,10,15,30]
})

# first create a DataFrame with all dates between specified start<-->end using pd.date_range()
all_dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(missing_df['date'].min(), missing_df['date'].max()), columns=['date'])

# from the all_dates DataFrame, left join onto the DataFrame with missing dates
new_df = all_dates.merge(right=missing_df, how='left', on='date')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s.asfreq('D').interpolate().asfreq('Q')
```