# Pandas Re-indexing command

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, dataframe

*RE [Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe), previously ask question

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range('09-01-2013', '09-30-2013')  

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [2,10,5,1], index = ["09-02-2013","09-03-2013","09-06-2013","09-07-2013"], columns = ["Events"])

df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index);  #question (1)

df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=np.nan)  
print(df)
```

In the above script what does the command noted as question one do?  If you leave this
command out of the script, the df will be re-indexed but the data portion of the
original df will not be retained.  As there is no reference to the df data in the
DatetimeIndex command, why is the data from the starting df lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index);` converts the string index of `df` to a DatetimeIndex.

---

You have to make the distinction between different types of indexes. In

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [2,10,5,1], index = ["09-02-2013","09-03-2013","09-06-2013","09-07-2013"], columns = ["Events"])
```

you have an **index containing strings**. When using

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index);
```

you convert this standard index with strings to an **index with datetimes** (a DatetimeIndex). So the values of these two types of indexes are completely different.

Now, when you reindex with

```
idx = pd.date_range('09-01-2013', '09-30-2013')  
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

where `idx` is also an **index with datetimes**. When you reindex the original `df` with a string index, there are no matching index values, so no column values of the original `df` are retained. When you reindex the second `df` (after converting the index to a datetime index), there will be matching index values, so the column values on those indixes are retained.

See also http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html