# reindex to add missing dates to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, date, pandas

I try to parse a CSV file which looks like this:

```
dd.mm.yyyy   value

01.01.2000   1
02.01.2000   2
01.02.2000   3
```

I need to add missing dates and fill according values with **NaN**. I used `Series.reindex` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd

ts=pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', parse_dates='True', index_col=0)

idx = pd.date_range('01.01.2000', '02.01.2000')

ts.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(ts.index)
ts = ts.reindex(idx, fill_value='NaN')
```

But in result, values for certain dates are swapped due to date format (i.e. mm/dd instead of dd/mm):

```
01.01.2000   1
02.01.2000   3
03.01.2000   NaN
...
...
31.01.2000   NaN
01.02.2000   2
```

I tried several ways (i.e. add `dayfirst=True` to `read_csv`) to do it right but still can't figure it out. Please, help.

Comment: You could try adding `dayfirst=True` to `read_csv()`.

Comment: Yes i have tried it, but result is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `parse_dates` to the first column with `parse_dates=[0]`:

```
ts = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, dayfirst=True)

idx = pd.date_range('01.01.2000', '02.01.2000')

ts.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(ts.index)
ts = ts.reindex(idx, fill_value='NaN')
print(ts)
```

prints:

```
              value
2000-01-01        1
2000-01-02        2
2000-01-03      NaN
...
2000-01-31      NaN
2000-02-01        3
```

`parse_dates=[0]` tells pandas to explicitly parse the first column as dates. From the docs:

> parse_dates : boolean, list of ints or names, list of lists, or dict
>
> If True -> try parsing the index.
>
> If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column.
>
> If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as a single date column.
>
> {'foo' : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result 'foo'
>
> A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.

Comment: @MikeMüller, Trying to use this but I have multiple entries per date, it's absence records from factory shifts.  So, we could have 2 records of people calling in sick on 8/5/2015 but then no more sick days till 8/9/2015 when we could have 3.  My code breaks at the line:

ts = ts.reindex(idx, fill_value='NaN')  

Can you answer that in this question or should I create a new one?  Thank you!

Comment: Go ahead and create a new question. Please and an example of what you try to achieve.

Comment: @MikeMüller, question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506038/pandas-reindex-to-fill-missing-dates-or-better-method-to-fill
Thank you for any insight you can provide!