# How to add missing dates to index with correct date format in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which looks like below

```
327,2018-02-12 23:30:18.255810+00:00,Pur,10.11.100.1,WSE,8.0,23.0,6.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
328,2018-02-12 23:30:22.718605+00:00,Bol,10.11.100.1,DEF,8.0,23.0,11.41,0.0,,,,,,,,
333,2018-02-13 00:00:17.886487+00:00,Cal,10.11.100.1,WSE,9.0,23.0,10.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
334,2018-02-13 00:00:21.948083+00:00,Moe,10.11.100.1,CFG,9.0,23.0,21.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
436,2018-02-15 11:00:11.137740+00:00,Cad,10.11.100.1,MOD,5.0,24.0,3.17,0.0,,,,,,,,
437,2018-02-15 11:27:20.994247+00:00,Ric,10.11.100.1,DEF,7.0,24.0,9.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
877,2018-02-17 01:34:10.662735+00:00,Pit,10.4.100.1,CFD,6.0,3.0,37.23,0.0,,,,,,,,
878,2018-02-20 00:04:39.855528+00:00,Bol,10.4.100.1,WSE,9.0,3.0,55.42,0.0,,,,,,,,
```

The date range is `2018-02-02` to `2018-04-13`

I have tried doing something like this as mentioned here [Pandas Reindex to Fill Missing Dates, or Better Method to Fill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506038/pandas-reindex-to-fill-missing-dates-or-better-method-to-fill)

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=["date"])
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
d2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2018-02-02','2018-04-13'))
print(df.join(d2,how='right'))
```

But this doesn't seem to work.I still have some missing dates.What is the correct way to fill up the missing dates and assign `0` to its associated values?

Comment: You have missing date , but the target df index format is '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'(datetime)?

Comment: The dates are unevenly spaced and given with a precision of microseconds. Which dates exactly are missing here? Can you post the expected date index for your data snippet?

Comment: @WolfgangK `2018-02-14`, `2018-02-16`, `2018-02-18` and `2018-02-19` as shown in the data snippet

Comment: @SouvikRay For example we have `2018-02-15 11:27:20.994247+00:00`, so what should be the exact format for the following day `2018-02-16`? Or can we just discard everything from hours downwards?

Comment: @WolfgangK discard everything from hour and downwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to convert your index to plain dates to make your own solution work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

df.index = df.index.date

d2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2018-02-12','2018-02-20'))
print(df.join(d2, how='right').fillna(0))
```

It should give

```
2018-02-12  327.0  Pur  10.11.100.1  WSE  8.0  23.0   6.50  0.0
2018-02-12  328.0  Bol  10.11.100.1  DEF  8.0  23.0  11.41  0.0
2018-02-13  333.0  Cal  10.11.100.1  WSE  9.0  23.0  10.50  0.0
2018-02-13  334.0  Moe  10.11.100.1  CFG  9.0  23.0  21.50  0.0
2018-02-14    0.0    0            0    0  0.0   0.0   0.00  0.0
2018-02-15  436.0  Cad  10.11.100.1  MOD  5.0  24.0   3.17  0.0
2018-02-15  437.0  Ric  10.11.100.1  DEF  7.0  24.0   9.50  0.0
2018-02-16    0.0    0            0    0  0.0   0.0   0.00  0.0
2018-02-17  877.0  Pit   10.4.100.1  CFD  6.0   3.0  37.23  0.0
2018-02-18    0.0    0            0    0  0.0   0.0   0.00  0.0
2018-02-19    0.0    0            0    0  0.0   0.0   0.00  0.0
2018-02-20  878.0  Bol   10.4.100.1  WSE  9.0   3.0  55.42  0.0
```