# Reindexing to Add Date Indices Not Working as Expected

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with this format

```
Index Date       A B
1     01-01-2000 1 1
2     01-03-2000 3 6
```

which I would like to index by date and fill in the missing date rows to create something like this

```
Date       A   B
01-01-2000 1   1
01-02-2000 NaN NaN
01-03-2000 3   6
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326546/reindex-to-add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe) I have created the below code, but the empty rows are still not being added.

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df = df.reindex(df.index)
```

Comment: You need to convert the datetime to datetime format frist , using pd.to_datetime

Comment: The `Date` column is of type `datetime64` before being set as the index.

Comment: Additionally when I convert the index again using `pd.to_datetime` the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.set_index('Date').reindex(pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2000-01-03'))
Out[90]: 
            Index    A    B
2000-01-01    1.0  1.0  1.0
2000-01-02    NaN  NaN  NaN
2000-01-03    2.0  3.0  6.0
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked although only after I separated it into two lines of code.