# How not to plot missing periods

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series, nan

I'm trying to plot a time series data, where for certain periods there is no data. Data is loaded into dataframe and I'm plotting it using `df.plot()`. The problem is that the missing periods get connected while plotting, giving an impression that value exists in that period, while it doesn't.

Here's an example of the problem

[image: problem]

There is no data between Sep 01 and Sep 08 as well as between Sep 09 and Sep 25, but the data is plotted in a way that it seems that there are values in that period.

I would like to have zero values visualized in that period, or no values at all. How to do that?

Just to be clear, I don't have NaN values for periods [Sep 01, Sep 08], [Sep 09, Sep 29], but no data at all (not even in the time index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the missing dates to your dataframe, with NaN values. Then, when plotted, those NaNs break the line -- you will get several line segments, with empty periods between them.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324591/2096752) explains best how to add the missing dates to your dataframe.  To summarize it, this should do the trick:

```
df = df.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index), fill_value=NaN)
```

Comment: Better is `df = df.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index))`, it add `NaN` by default. If want specify `NaN` - `df = df.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index), fill_value=np.nan)`

Answer (score 4):

Consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series(
    np.arange(10), pd.date_range('2016-03-31', periods=10)
).replace({3: np.nan, 6: np.nan})

s.plot()
```

[image]

You can see the `np.nan` were skipped.
However:

```
s.fillna(0).plot()
```

[image]

`0`s are not skipped.

I suggest `s.replace(0, np.nan).plot()`