# pandas.DatetimeIndex frequency is None and can't be set

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

I created a DatetimeIndex from a "date" column:

```
sales.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(sales["date"])
```

Now the index looks as follows:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2003-01-02', '2003-01-03', '2003-01-04', '2003-01-06',
                   '2003-01-07', '2003-01-08', '2003-01-09', '2003-01-10',
                   '2003-01-11', '2003-01-13',
                   ...
                   '2016-07-22', '2016-07-23', '2016-07-24', '2016-07-25',
                   '2016-07-26', '2016-07-27', '2016-07-28', '2016-07-29',
                   '2016-07-30', '2016-07-31'],
                  dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=4393, freq=None)
```

As you see, the `freq` attribute is None. I suspect that errors down the road are caused by the missing `freq`. However, if I try to set the frequency explicitly:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-30857144de81> in <module>()
      1 #### DEBUG
----> 2 sales_train = disentangle(df_train)
      3 sales_holdout = disentangle(df_holdout)
      4 result = sarima_fit_predict(sales_train.loc[5002, 9990]["amount_sold"], sales_holdout.loc[5002, 9990]["amount_sold"])

<ipython-input-147-08b4c4ecdea3> in disentangle(df_train)
      2     # transform sales table to disentangle sales time series
      3     sales = df_train[["date", "store_id", "article_id", "amount_sold"]]
----> 4     sales.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(sales["date"], freq="d")
      5     sales = sales.pivot_table(index=["store_id", "article_id", "date"])
      6     return sales

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 else:
     90                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         return wrapper
     93     return _deprecate_kwarg

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in __new__(cls, data, freq, start, end, periods, copy, name, tz, verify_integrity, normalize, closed, ambiguous, dtype, **kwargs)
    399                                          'dates does not conform to passed '
    400                                          'frequency {1}'
--> 401                                          .format(inferred, freq.freqstr))
    402 
    403         if freq_infer:

ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed dates does not conform to passed frequency D
```

So apparently a frequency has been inferred, but is stored neither in the `freq` nor `inferred_freq` attribute of the DatetimeIndex - both are None. Can someone clear up the confusion?

Comment: does `sales.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(sales["date"].asfreq(freq='D'))` work?

Comment: No. "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 218153 elements, new values have 1 elements"

Comment: Your data sample does not have a frequency per-se. Judging the information you provide, 2003-01-05 and 2003-01-12 are missing.
Moreover, 2003-01-05 + 4393 days makes 2015-01-12, not 2016-07-31.

Comment: I'm not sure why @EdChum's answer wouldn't work.  Maybe syntax issue?  See my anwer where I applied `asfreq` to the whole dataframe rather than just the index.  If that's not the issue it may be hard to say unless you can post a smaller sample dataframe that exhibits the same issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have a couple options here:

- `pd.infer_freq`
- `pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset`

> I suspect that errors down the road are caused by the missing freq.

You are absolutely right.  Here's what I use often:

```
def add_freq(idx, freq=None):
    """Add a frequency attribute to idx, through inference or directly.

    Returns a copy.  If `freq` is None, it is inferred.
    """

    idx = idx.copy()
    if freq is None:
        if idx.freq is None:
            freq = pd.infer_freq(idx)
        else:
            return idx
    idx.freq = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset(freq)
    if idx.freq is None:
        raise AttributeError('no discernible frequency found to `idx`.  Specify'
                             ' a frequency string with `freq`.')
    return idx
```

An example:

```
idx=pd.to_datetime(['2003-01-02', '2003-01-03', '2003-01-06'])  # freq=None

print(add_freq(idx))  # inferred
DatetimeIndex(['2003-01-02', '2003-01-03', '2003-01-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')

print(add_freq(idx, freq='D'))  # explicit
DatetimeIndex(['2003-01-02', '2003-01-03', '2003-01-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Using `asfreq` will actually reindex (fill) missing dates, so be careful of that if that's not what you're looking for.

> The primary function for changing frequencies is the `asfreq` function.
>   For a `DatetimeIndex`, this is basically just a thin, but convenient
>   wrapper around `reindex` which generates a `date_range` and calls `reindex`.

Comment: In Python 3.7.10 this code produces an error. Specifically, the line `print(add_freq(idx, freq='D'))` produces `ValueError: Inferred frequency B from passed values does not conform to passed frequency D`

Comment: I can confirm about this error.

Answer (score 13):

It seems to relate to missing dates as 3kt notes.  You might be able to "fix" with `asfreq('D')` as EdChum suggests but that gives you a continuous index with missing data values.  It works fine for some some sample data I made up:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'x':[1,2,4] }, 
   index=pd.to_datetime(['2003-01-02', '2003-01-03', '2003-01-06']) )

df
Out[756]: 
            x
2003-01-02  1
2003-01-03  2
2003-01-06  4

df.index
Out[757]: DatetimeIndex(['2003-01-02', '2003-01-03', '2003-01-06'], 
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Note that `freq=None`.  If you apply `asfreq('D')`, this changes to `freq='D'`:

```
df.asfreq('D')
Out[758]: 
              x
2003-01-02  1.0
2003-01-03  2.0
2003-01-04  NaN
2003-01-05  NaN
2003-01-06  4.0

df.asfreq('d').index
Out[759]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2003-01-02', '2003-01-03', '2003-01-04', '2003-01-05',
               '2003-01-06'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

More generally, and depending on what exactly you are trying to do, you might want to check out the following for other options like reindex & resample:  [Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: This pointed me into the right direction. What I did was to simply rebuild the broken index like this: `df.index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq="h")`

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if earlier versions of python have this, but 3.6 has this simple solution:

```
# 'b' stands for business days
# 'w' for weekly, 'd' for daily, and you get the idea...
df.index.freq = 'b'
```

Comment: for my index: `DatetimeIndex(['2012-12-31', '2013-12-31', '2014-12-31', '2015-12-31',
               '2016-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2019-12-31',
               '2020-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2022-01-27'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)` this produced nothing. Not sure why

Answer (score 3):

It could happen if for examples the dates you are passing aren't sorted.

Look at this example:

```
example_ts = pd.Series(data=range(10),
                       index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-10', freq='D'))
example_ts.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(np.hstack([example_ts.index[-1:],
                                               example_ts.index[:-1]]), freq='D')
```

The previous code goes into your error, because of the non-sequential dates.

```
example_ts = pd.Series(data=range(10),
                       index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-10', freq='D'))
example_ts.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(np.hstack([example_ts.index[:-1],
                                               example_ts.index[-1:]]), freq='D')
```

This one runs correctly, instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with missing values in the index. I have simply re-build the index based on the original index in the frequency I needed:

```
df.index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq="h")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I was having the same error. I was not able to resolve my issue by suggestions posted above but solved it using the below solution.

[Pandas DatetimeIndex + seasonal_decompose = missing frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246322/pandas-datetimeindex-seasonal-decompose-missing-frequency).

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Similar to some of the other answers here, my problem was that my data had missing dates.

Instead of dealing with this issue in Python, I opted to change my SQL query that I was using to source the data. So instead of skipping dates, I wrote the query such that it would fill in missing dates with the value 0.