# Pandas DatetimeIndex + seasonal_decompose = missing frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to do a `seasonal_decompose` on my pandas dataframe but I've encountered an error that I can't get past. My time series data contains chronological gaps which is sensible considering my data is stock prices (after market hours create these gaps, as well as differing month lengths, etc.). The data in of itself can be thought of as contiguous however pandas doesn't seem to want to infer any frequency.

All of my timeframe data (1m, 5m, 15m ... 1D, 1M) is populated correctly but with None set as the frequency. My algorithm creates an empty dataframe upon instantiation and adds values to it via `loc` as the data arrives during the course of the algorithm's runtime. So perhaps that's ultimately why the frequency is None (as Pandas is typically used after all data is generated).

I've tried explicitly setting the frequency right before `seasonal_decompose` using:

`data.index.freq = data.index.freq or to_offset(timeframe.Timespan).freqstr`

where timeframe.Timespan is a python timedelta object. The resulting string is accurate ("D" because the timespan happens to be daily) but the following error occurs:

> ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency D

So I can't explicitly set the frequency on my index? How do I solve this? How is the frequency integer (being passed to `seasonal_decompose`) derived from these strings anyway? I'm also not permitted to change the value of `data.index.inferred_freq` so that's not an option.

Comment: have you tried `data.asfreq`? I suppose in this case it'd be `data.asfreq(data.index.freq or to_offset(timeframe.Timespan).freqstr)`

Comment: Won't that change the data respective to the original? I'd like to keep my timestamps the same. I have to compare my predictions to the original dataset. Or would I do asfreq and then dropna?

Comment: _"My time series data contains chronological gaps"_ then you can't set the frequency as-is, because the index is not actually of the given frequency.  To set the frequency every element in your index must separated by `freq` units, i.e. if your index jumps from `'2018-01-01'` to `'2018-01-03'` you can't set it the frequency to `'D'` as you're missing a day.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake You need to have a continuous range for `freq` to work. Calling `asfreq` would indeed adjust your index and create entries for any missing time periods (using `None` as the default value). If you call `dropna` you'd lose your `freq` again.

Comment: What would you suggest I do in this situation? Should I fill in the NAs with a value? If so, how? At first thought there are many ways to treat the data, all which would affect the predictions. If I keep the NAs will I even be able to do a seasonal_decompose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is [DataFrame.asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
data = data.asfreq(data.index.freq or to_offset(timeframe.Timespan).freqstr)
```

Comment: What does inplace do in this situation? I can't find it anywhere in the link.

Comment: Oops, no `inplace` for this one. I guess you have to reassign after calling `asfreq`

Comment: Given that I've yet to produce predictions I cannot say that the following solution yields accurate results; in addition to your solution I've interpolated the missing data using data.interpolate(inplace=True) and everything is in working order. Thank you!