# Impute missing dates to multilevel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

dates = ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04']
dates_list =[ dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in dates]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 2),
                  index=[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dates_list],
                  columns=['data1', 'data2'])
```

-

```
df
                  data1     data2
a   2000-01-01  0.928427    0.029868
    2000-01-03  0.243949    0.140281
b   2000-01-03  0.760319    0.897673
    2000-01-04  0.288415    0.919107
```

I want to impute the missing max and min date rows for every index value, with some value set for the data columns (i.e 0). Such that my dataframe would look like:

```
                data1   data2
a   2000-01-01  0.507132    0.649724
    2000-01-02  0.0         0.0
    2000-01-03  0.500277    0.859769
    2000-01-04  0.0         0.0
b   2000-01-01  0.0         0.0
    2000-01-02  0.0         0.0
    2000-01-03  0.136397    0.166815
    2000-01-04  0.102095    0.918545
```

I've tried using the methods described in:
[pandas fill missing dates in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231496/pandas-fill-missing-dates-in-time-series) and [Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe) as:

```
 df.loc[dates_list]
```

->

```
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'
```

but am unable to get it to work for a multilevel indexed df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing with `reindex`

```
id=df.index.get_level_values(1)
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0],pd.date_range(id.min(),id.max())])
idx
Out[325]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b'], [2000-01-01 00:00:00, 2000-01-02 00:00:00, 2000-01-03 00:00:00, 2000-01-04 00:00:00]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
df=df.reindex(idx,fill_value=0)
df
Out[326]: 
                 data1     data2
a 2000-01-01  0.898764  0.091644
  2000-01-02  0.000000  0.000000
  2000-01-03  0.397724  0.742387
  2000-01-04  0.000000  0.000000
b 2000-01-01  0.000000  0.000000
  2000-01-02  0.000000  0.000000
  2000-01-03  0.187021  0.203479
  2000-01-04  0.231994  0.935882
```