# Pandas Filling missing data in Time series dataframe with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge pandas dataframe containing Time and Acceleration. some of the data sets are missing, and I need to rebuild them.
This is a picture of the missing part. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsNa5.png

I need to add some NaN in the cells in the dataset, so i can rebuild

This is a picture of the dataset.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDnAH.png

I need to add data between 99 and 199.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also be more specific about your problem, e.g. how do you want the area to be filled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas fill missing dates in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231496/pandas-fill-missing-dates-in-time-series)