# Pandas - fill missing date value of dataframe and copying column values except for one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question regarding how to fill missint date values in a pandas dataframe.
I found a similar question ( [pandas fill missing dates in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231496/pandas-fill-missing-dates-in-time-series) )

but this doesn't answer my actual question.

I have a dataframe looking something like this:

```
date            amount   person   country
01.01.2019      10       John     IT
01.03.2019      5        Jane     SWE
01.05.2019      3        Jim      SWE
01.05.2019      10       Jim      SWE
02.01.2019      10       Bob      UK
02.01.2019      10       Jane     SWE
02.03.2019      10       Sue      IT
```

As you can see, there are missing values in the dates.
What I need to do is to fill the missing date-values and fill remaining column values with the values from the previous line, EXCEPT for the column 'amount', which I need to be a 0, otherwise I would falsify my amounts.

I know there is a command for that in Pandas ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html ) but I'm not sure how to apply that to filling missing values.

```
data = data.reindex(pd.date_range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-03")) 

method='backfill') , fill_value="0") ?
```

The expected output would be as follows:

```
date            amount   person   country
01.01.2019      10       John     IT
01.02.2019      0        Jane     SWE
01.03.2019      5        Jane     SWE
01.04.2019      0        Jane     SWE
01.05.2019      3        Jim      SWE
01.05.2019      10       Jim      SWE
02.01.2019      10       Bob      UK
02.01.2019      10       Jane     SWE
02.02.2019      0        Jane     SWE
02.03.2019      10       Sue      IT
```

I would appreciate any help on that regard.

Thank you and BR

Answer (score 0):

I think simpliest is replace missing values in 2 steps:

```
data = data.reindex(pd.date_range("2014-11-01", "2019-10-31")) 
data['amount'] = data['amount'].fillna(0)
data = data.bfill()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your fast reply.
I tried that, and the result was partially satisfying.
My 'amount' column is filled with 0's as expected, but the other columns are filled with 'NaN'.
Also, for some reason - my dataframe got significantly (from 2+ million entries to 1826).

Could the reason for that be, that I'm not actually using the date in my initial dataframe ?

Comment: @Melany - Is there `DatetimeIndex` in input `df` ? What is `print (df.index.max())` and `print (df.index.min())` ?

Comment: I set the date as the index now, before it was just an ascending number.
now I tried again and I'm getting the error 

"ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

which seems to be a common issue. 

data.index.min(): 2014-01-11 00:00:00
data.index.max(): 2019-12-10 00:00:00

Comment: @Melany - Error means there are duplicated dates, not like in sample data bu e.g. if change `01.02.2019` to `01.01.2019` like first date, how values are processing?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not change anything.
Is it possible to solve this with the reindex command? 
Because I can imagine there being issues with duplicate index values.

Comment: @Melany - I edit your sample data like in your real data (duplicated datetimes), how looks expected output? Can you add it to question by  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64350787/edit) ?

Comment: I realised my initial post was a bit misleading, so I edited it to mimic my actual data more accurately.

Comment: @Melany - Can you add expected output? How looks data in final dataframe?

Comment: I inserted the expected outlook in my initial post, thank you for noting that.

Comment: @Melany - Is output correct? I cannot see logic here - why some rows are expanded in january, another in february? There is not necessary grouping by `person, country` and expand datetimes? What date range is used in sample data - expected output?