# Using asfreq to resample a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**EDIT:** *I had made a mistake and my index was starting at 00:00:00, not at 06:00:00 (see below). So this question is spurious, but of course Wen's solution is correct.*

I have a dataframe whose index goes like this:

```
2017-11-01 06:00:00
2017-11-02 06:00:00 
2017-11-03 06:00:00
...
```

and so on. But I have the suspicion there're missing entries, for instance, index for `2017-11-04 06:00:00` could be missing. I have used

```
df = df.asfreq(freq="1D")
```

to fill with `NaN` the missing values, but it creates a new index that doesn't take into consideration the hours, it goes `2017-11-01, 2017-11-02` and so on, so the values in the adjacent column are all `NaN`!

How can I fix this? I don't see any option in `asfreq` that can solve it. Perhaps other tool? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `df.index[:10]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It work find on my side

```
l=[
'2017-11-01 06:00:00',
'2017-11-03 06:00:00']

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(l)), index=l)
ts.index=pd.to_datetime(ts.index)
ts.asfreq(freq="D")
Out[745]: 
2017-11-01 06:00:00   -0.467919
2017-11-02 06:00:00         NaN
2017-11-03 06:00:00    1.610024
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```