# How to lag data by x specific days on a multi index pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pandas-loc

I have a DataFrame that has dates, assets, and then price/volume data. I'm trying to pull in data from 7 days ago, but the issue is that I can't use shift() because my table has missing dates in it.

```
 date   cusip   price   price_7daysago
1/1/2017    a   1   
1/1/2017    b   2   
1/2/2017    a   1.2 
1/2/2017    b   2.3 
1/8/2017    a   1.1         1
1/8/2017    b   2.2         2
```

I've tried creating a lambda function to try to use loc and timedelta to create this shifting, but I was only able to output empty numpy arrays:

```
def row_delta(x, df, days, colname):
    if datetime.strptime(x['recorddate'], '%Y%m%d') - timedelta(days) in [datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d') for x in   df['recorddate'].unique().tolist()]:
        return df.loc[(df['recorddate_date'] == df['recorddate_date'] - timedelta(days)) & (df['cusip'] == x['cusip']) ,colname]
    else:
        return 'nothing'
```

I also thought of doing something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe) in order to fill in missing dates, but my issue is that I have multiple indexes, the dates and the cusips so I can't just reindex on this.

Comment: What's desired output?

Comment: sorry for the confusion- updated with desired output (the lag from 7 days ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` the `DataFrame` with itself while adding 7 days to the date column for the right Frame. Use the `suffixes` argument to name the columns appropriately.

```
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.merge(df.assign(date = df.date+pd.Timedelta(days=7)), 
         on=['date', 'cusip'],
         how='left', suffixes=['', '_7daysago'])
```

Output: `df`

```
        date cusip  price  price_7daysago
0 2017-01-01     a    1.0             NaN
1 2017-01-01     b    2.0             NaN
2 2017-01-02     a    1.2             NaN
3 2017-01-02     b    2.3             NaN
4 2017-01-08     a    1.1             1.0
5 2017-01-08     b    2.2             2.0
```

Comment: Haha... both of us focusing on this question, can do `fillna` for replacing `nan`s with `''`

Answer (score 0):

you can set `date` and `cusip` as index and use `unstack` and `shift` together

```
shifted = df.set_index(["date", "cusip"]).unstack().shift(7).stack()
```

then simply merge `shifted` with your original `df`