# How to use pandas to auto fill missing dates?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In my dataframe, I have a column named "Date" that runs from 2020-01-01 to 2020-04-16 (108 rows).

```
2020-01-01,
2020-01-02,
2020-01-03,
2020-01-04,
2020-01-05,
2020-01-06,
....
2020-04-16
```

How can I autofill the remaining of the dates in 2020, so that the "Date" column would look like this (366 rows):

```
2020-01-01,
2020-01-02,
2020-01-03,
2020-01-04,
2020-01-05,
2020-01-06,
....
**2020-12-31**
```

This is just for the "Date" column. I do not need to fill other columns.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The other columns are going to have Null values for the dates that you're adding in?

Comment: @LTheriault I am good with the values from the other columns (they have non-NaN values) I just need the "Date" column to be filled till 2020-12-31.

Comment: maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324591/10197418 ?