# Adding missing dates to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a list of One Piece manga, which currently looks like this:

```
0           #                                     Title Pages
Date                                                         
1997-07-19  1  Romance Dawn - The Dawn of the Adventure    53
1997-07-28  2               That Guy, "Straw Hat Luffy"    23
1997-08-04  3          Introducing "Pirate Hunter Zoro"    21
1997-08-11  4          Marine Captain "Axe-Hand Morgan"    19
1997-08-25  5          Pirate King and Master Swordsman    19
1997-09-01  6                     The First Crew Member    23
1997-09-08  7                                   Friends    20
1997-09-13  8                          Introducing Nami    19
```

Although every episode is to be issued weekly, sometimes they are delayed or on break, resulting in an irregular interval in the dates. What I would like to do is to add a missing date. For example, between 1997-08-11 and 1997-08-25, there should be 1997-08-18 (7 days from 1997-08-11) where the episode was not issued. Could you help me out with how to operate this code?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I don't think so because I need to fill in dates for an interval > = 2 weeks. re-index or re-sample doesn't provide the frequency. I think I would need some sort of function for this.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. You want to fill-in the dates, but only when the gap is >= 14 days? and the date in the middle should be in 1 week intervals? There seems to be a couple of corner cases that might be difficult to properly determine. Such as a gap of 22 days. Filling in 7D intervals will leave you with a 1 day interval (in the end). Is this the desired output?

Comment: The next record is 9 days free from the first record. Are there any new rules as the date interval is not necessarily every week?

Answer (score 0):

I used `relativedelta` and list comprehension to get a 14-day interval per row and `.shift(1)` to compare to another row with `.np.where()` with a `1` returning a row where we would want to insert a row before. Then, I looped through the dataframe and appended the relevant rows to another dataframe. Then, I used `pd.concat` to bring the two dataframes together, sorted by date, deleted the helper columns and reset the index.

There may be some gaps as others have mentioned like 22 days+ but this should get you in the right direction. Perhaps you could turn it into a function and run it multiple times, which is why I added `.reset_index(drop=True)` at the end. Obviously, you could just make this more advanced, but I hope this helps.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '1997-07-19',
  1: '1997-07-28',
  2: '1997-08-04',
  3: '1997-08-11',
  4: '1997-08-25',
  5: '1997-09-01',
  6: '1997-09-08',
  7: '1997-09-13'},
 '#': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8},
 'Title': {0: 'Romance Dawn - The Dawn of the Adventure',
  1: 'That Guy, "Straw Hat Luffy"',
  2: 'Introducing "Pirate Hunter Zoro"',
  3: 'Marine Captain "Axe-Hand Morgan"',
  4: 'Pirate King and Master Swordsman',
  5: 'The First Crew Member',
  6: 'Friends',
  7: 'Introducing Nami'},
 'Pages': {0: 53, 1: 23, 2: 21, 3: 19, 4: 19, 5: 23, 6: 20, 7: 19}})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date2'] = [d - relativedelta(days=-14) for d in df['Date']]
df['Date3'] = np.where((df['Date'] >= df['Date2'].shift(1)), 1 , 0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({})
n=0
for j in (df['Date3']):
    n+=1
    if j == 1:
        new_row = pd.DataFrame({"Date": df['Date'][n-1] - relativedelta(days=7)}, index=[n])
        df1=df1.append(new_row)
df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_values('Date').drop(['Date2', 'Date3'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

Output:

```
    Date        #    Title                                      Pages
0   1997-07-19  1.0  Romance Dawn - The Dawn of the Adventure   53.0
1   1997-07-28  2.0  That Guy, "Straw Hat Luffy"                23.0
2   1997-08-04  3.0  Introducing "Pirate Hunter Zoro"           21.0
3   1997-08-11  4.0  Marine Captain "Axe-Hand Morgan"           19.0
4   1997-08-18  NaN  NaN                                        NaN
5   1997-08-25  5.0  Pirate King and Master Swordsman           19.0
6   1997-09-01  6.0  The First Crew Member                      23.0
7   1997-09-08  7.0  Friends                                    20.0
8   1997-09-13  8.0  Introducing Nami                           19.0
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I would like to achieve. I am having a hard time understanding your np.where function and loop. Could you explain what these lines try to achieve?

Comment: The np.where is comparing Date to Date2 and returns a 1 if there is a 14 day or more gap. Then, later in the loop `for j in (df['Date3']):
    n+=1  if j == 1:'` The code `if j == 1:` is using that logic ressult of 1 from the earlier np.where to insert a row. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You sould use the `shift` builtin function.

```py
df['day_between'] =  df['Date'].shift(-1) - df['Date']
```

output of `print(df[['Date', 'day_between']])` is then:

```py
        Date day_between
0 1997-07-19      9 days
1 1997-07-28      7 days
2 1997-08-04      7 days
3 1997-08-11     14 days
4 1997-08-25      7 days
5 1997-09-01      7 days
6 1997-09-08      5 days
7 1997-09-13         NaT
```