# Add Missing Date Index in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a multi index data frame that has a date column and location_id as indices.

```py
index_1 = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04']
index_2 = [100,200,300]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([index_1, 
index_2], names=['Date', 'location_id'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,100,9), index)
df

                         0
Date       location_id    
2020-01-01 100          19
           200          75
           300          39
2020-01-03 100          11
           200          91
           300          80
2020-01-04 100          36
           200          56
           300          54
```

I want to fill in missing dates, with just one location_id and fill it with 0:

```py
                         0
Date       location_id    
2020-01-01 100          19
           200          75
           300          39
2020-01-02 100          0
2020-01-03 100          11
           200          91
           300          80
2020-01-04 100          36
           200          56
           300          54
```

How can I achieve that? [This is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe) but only if my data frame was not multi indexed.

Comment: What's the logic for the second index? Is it always going to be `100` or could it have another value?

Comment: It can be any number from location_id, in this case `200` or `300` should be be ok too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.unique.html) value of the Date index level, generate all dates between min and max with [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and use [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) with unique value of Date to get the missing one. Then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) df with the [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) of the original index and a `MultiIndex.from_product` made of missing date and the `min` of the level location_id.

```
#unique dates
m = df.index.unique(level=0)
# reindex
df = df.reindex(df.index.union(
                   pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range(m.min(), m.max())
                                                .difference(pd.to_datetime(m))
                                                .strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
                                             [df.index.get_level_values(1).min()]])), 
                fill_value=0)
print(df)
                 0
2020-01-01 100  91
           200  49
           300  19
2020-01-02 100   0
2020-01-03 100  41
           200  25
           300  51
2020-01-04 100  44
           200  40
           300  54
```

instead of `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`, you can also use `product` from `itertools`. Same result but maybe faster.

```
from itertools import product
df = df.reindex(df.index.union(
                  list(product(pd.date_range(m.min(), m.max())
                                 .difference(pd.to_datetime(m))
                                 .strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                               [df.index.get_level_values(1).min()]))),
                fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Let's say my date is column is by hour increments instead of day, then I need to change `('%Y-%m-%d')` to `('%Y-%m-%d-%h')`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Rob like this I would say yes, I used `'%Y-%m-%d'` because it matches your original index, so the one you used should match the format of the original index

Comment: @Rob and laso you need to specify the freq in date_range, like `pd.date_range(m.min(), m.max(), freq='1H)`, the day is the default freq

Answer (score 3):

Pandas index is immutable, so you need to construct a new index. Put index level `location_id` to column and get unique rows and call `asfreq` to create rows for missing date. Assign the result to `df2`. Finally, use `df.align` to join both indices and `fillna`

```
df1 = df.reset_index(-1)
df2 = df1.loc[~df1.index.duplicated()].asfreq('D').ffill()
df_final = df.align(df2.set_index('location_id', append=True))[0].fillna(0)

Out[75]:
                           0
Date       location_id
2020-01-01 100          19.0
           200          75.0
           300          39.0
2020-01-02 100           0.0
2020-01-03 100          11.0
           200          91.0
           300          80.0
2020-01-04 100          36.0
           200          56.0
           300          54.0
```

Comment: I tried this answer. This gave me the data frame I wanted, but also duplicated the date index, so for instance I have both `2020-01-01` and `2020-01-01 00:00:00` as indices in the same level. The former has the correct values, while the latter has `NaN` under `location_id` and `0.0` under column `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`unstack/stack` and `asfreq/reindex` would work:

```
new_df = df.unstack(fill_value=0)

new_df.index = pd.to_datetime(new_df.index)

new_df.asfreq('D').fillna(0).stack('location_id')
```

Output:

```
                           0
Date       location_id      
2020-01-01 100          78.0
           200          25.0
           300          89.0
2020-01-02 100           0.0
           200           0.0
           300           0.0
2020-01-03 100          79.0
           200          23.0
           300          11.0
2020-01-04 100          30.0
           200          79.0
           300          72.0
```

Comment: This works well, but because I am working with a big data frame, it adds computation time. Is it possible to only add one value for each missing date, as in the example in my question?