# Pandas reindex to fill date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

How to `reindex` this df to fill missing dates.

```
           query    min max mean
DATE                
2020-07-04  kabel   573 838 666.547619
2020-07-13  kabel   681 681 681.000000
2020-07-15  kabel   583 738 654.565217
```

**As output I want to get**

```
               query    min max mean
DATE                
2020-07-04  kabel   573 838 666.547619
2020-07-05  kabel   None None None
...         ...     ...  ...  ...
2020-07-12  kabel   None None None
2020-07-13  kabel   681 681 681.000000
2020-07-15  kabel   583 738 654.565217
```

Comment: You can try this link which uses Series.reindex:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I think  in the output the date after `2020-07-13` should be `2020-07-14`, Right?

Comment: Yes, right after `2020-07-13` there should be also `2020-07-14 kabel   None None None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) convert the index of dataframe to `DatetimeIndex`, then use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) to reindex the dataframe with `daily` frequency and use [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) to forward fill the values in `query` column:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.asfreq('D').assign(query=lambda x: x['query'].ffill())
```

Result:

```
print(df)
            query    min    max        mean
DATE                                       
2020-07-04  kabel  573.0  838.0  666.547619
2020-07-05  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-06  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-07  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-08  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-09  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-10  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-11  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-12  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-13  kabel  681.0  681.0  681.000000
2020-07-14  kabel    NaN    NaN         NaN
2020-07-15  kabel  583.0  738.0  654.565217
```