# Fill missing composite indexes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

My raw data looks like this:

```
raw_data = [
    {
        "date": "02.08.2020",
        "status": "A",
        "id": 3948,
    },
    {
        "date": "02.08.2020",
        "status": "B",
        "id": 495,
    },
    {
        "date": "03.08.2020",
        "status": "A",
        "id": 433,
    },
    {
        "date": "03.08.2020",
        "status": "B",
        "id": 845,
    },
    {
        "date": "03.08.2020",
        "status": "B",
        "id": 54,
    },
    {
        "date": "03.08.2020",
        "status": "C",
        "id": 133,
    },
    {
        "date": "04.08.2020",
        "status": "B",
        "id": 384,
    },
    {
        "date": "04.08.2020",
        "status": "C",
        "id": 1234,
    },
]
```

Then I create a pandas dataframe from it and group by date and status to get the count per date, per status:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
grp = df.groupby(['date', 'status']).size().to_frame(name = 'count').reset_index()

print(grp)
```

The output:

```
0  02.08.2020      A      1
1  02.08.2020      B      1
2  03.08.2020      A      1
3  03.08.2020      B      2
4  03.08.2020      C      1
5  04.08.2020      B      1
6  04.08.2020      C      1
```

I then chart this using seaborn:

```
sns.barplot(x="date", y="count", hue="status", data=grp)
plt.show()
```

And the chart looks like this:

[image]

Now that's cool, it visualises the status per day. But what I would like to do is fill the "gaps" between the days, because I might need to actually visualise the data starting from 01.08.2020 to 05.08.2020. I would like my dataframe to look like this:

```
0   01.08.2020      A      0    <<< added 3 empty rows for 01.08.2020 bc. no data
1   01.08.2020      B      0    <<<
2   01.08.2020      C      0    <<<
3   02.08.2020      A      1
4   02.08.2020      B      1
5   03.08.2020      A      1
6   03.08.2020      B      2
7   03.08.2020      C      1
8   04.08.2020      B      1
9   04.08.2020      C      1
10  05.08.2020      A      0    <<< added 3 empty rows for 05.08.2020 bc. no data
11  05.08.2020      B      0    <<<
12  05.08.2020      C      0    <<<
```

The idea is to have all days from 01.08 to 05.08 in the charts x-axis, even if there is no data for a given day. The goal is to make the x-axis continuous with all days from 01.08.2020 to 05.08.2020, data or no data.

I had a look at another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is about adding missing days in a datetime index. It's kind of what I want, but I also need to have the status per day empty I guess.

Can I create a dataframe like I want with builtin pandas functionality?

Comment: the y axis anyway starts at 0, when you fill the missing dates with 0 what do you expect to plot?

Comment: I expect to plot all days on the x-axis.

Comment: Do you really need to fill in your dataframe, or just change the plot?

Comment: @PaulH changing the plot is what I want to do. I thought this only works by having the data in the dataframe structured in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using Multi-index and re-index:

```
idx = pd.date_range('2020-08-01','2020-08-05').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((idx,(df['status'].unique())),names=['date','status'])
grp = (df.groupby(['date', 'status']).size().reindex(idx1,fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(name="count"))

sns.barplot(x="date", y="count", hue="status", data=grp)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Globally, you can use `reindex` at some point, here is one way to create `grp` with the missing value you want. One could go by using `groupby.size` as you did as well for similar idea result

```
grp = (df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='status',
                      aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
         .reindex(pd.Index(pd.date_range('2020-08-01', '2020-08-05').strftime('%d.%m.%Y'),
                           name='date'), 
                  fill_value=0)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='count')
      )
print(grp)
          date status  count
0   01.08.2020      A      0
1   01.08.2020      B      0
2   01.08.2020      C      0
3   02.08.2020      A      1
4   02.08.2020      B      1
5   02.08.2020      C      0
6   03.08.2020      A      1
7   03.08.2020      B      2
8   03.08.2020      C      1
9   04.08.2020      A      0
10  04.08.2020      B      1
11  04.08.2020      C      1
12  05.08.2020      A      0
13  05.08.2020      B      0
14  05.08.2020      C      0
```