# Add rows for missing hourly data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns: `Created'(%Y-%m-%d %H)` and `Count` which is an integer.

It is counting the amount of "tickets" registered per hour.

The problem is that there are many hours in the day that there are not registered any tickets.

I would like to add these hours as new rows with a `Count` of `0`. The dataframe looks like this:

```
    Created       Count
0   2020-10-26 10   11

1   2020-10-26 09   123

2   2020-10-26 08   36

3   2020-10-26 07   28

4   2020-10-26 06   7
```

But I would need it to add rows like this:

```
    Created           Count
    enter code here

0   2020-10-26 10   11

1   2020-10-26 09   123

2   2020-10-26 08   36

3   2020-10-26 07   28

4   2020-10-26 06   7

1  2020-10-26 05.   0

3  2020-10-26 04.   0
```

Also adding that it needs to be able to update continuously as new dates are added to the original dataframe.

Comment: [Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19324453/7259176) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can resample with:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Created': ['2020-10-26 10', '2020-10-26 08','2020-10-26 09','2020-10-26 07','2020-10-26 06'],
'count': [11, 10,14,16,20]})



df['Created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H')
df.sort_values(by=['Created'],inplace=True)
df.set_index('Created',inplace=True)


df_Date=pd.date_range(start=df.index.min().replace(hour=0), end=(df.index.max()), freq='H')
df=df.reindex(df_Date,fill_value=0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index': 'Created'},inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
               Created  count
0  2020-10-26 00:00:00      0
1  2020-10-26 01:00:00      0
2  2020-10-26 02:00:00      0
3  2020-10-26 03:00:00      0
4  2020-10-26 04:00:00      0
5  2020-10-26 05:00:00      0
6  2020-10-26 06:00:00     20
7  2020-10-26 07:00:00     16
8  2020-10-26 08:00:00     10
9  2020-10-26 09:00:00     14
10 2020-10-26 10:00:00     11
```

Comment: Somehow this gives me some odd values when I try to add it on the whole dataframe. It works perfectly fine when I set the df as you did above though. I get a lot of repetitive values, as well as a lot of 1's.

Comment: @Tina Marie Try [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) without specifying the `ffill` method: `df=df.reindex(df_Date,fill_value=0)`