# How to find out discontinuous date time index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, delta

I would like to know is there a way to pandas to detect if some date are missing from a datetime index ? I got two columns with some dates and a mileage of car. My goal is to complete my missing dataframes with an average of the miles by day on the missing days.

```
Actual
2020-10-26,2232
2020-10-27,2260
2020-12-27,4813
```

```
Objective
2020-10-26,2232
2020-10-27,2260
2020-10-28,
2020-10-29,
[...]
2020-12-26,
2020-12-27,4813
```

Comment: hmm, don't understand the actual question

Comment: Maybe what you need is something like Series.reindex?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: The idea is to complete the dataframe date by the missing one. I don't know if I'm clear but my aim objective is to have all the dates and recreate the missing ones

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is something similar to the `asfreq` method. Documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).