# How to fill a pandas df with rows for values that do not exist in a column and then fill na backwards?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'week': [1,2,4,5,7], 'items':[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

I would like to fill `foo` with rows for the "missing" weeks from `1` to `7` and then for these rows the `items` column should have as value the previous non-na value

The output dataframe should look like this:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'week': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'items':[1,2,2,3,4,4,5]}
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: set_index, reindex with the range of min and max of weeks, then ffill., did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `set_index()` method,`reindex()` method,`ffill()` method and `reset_index()` method:

```
resultdf=foo.set_index('week').reindex(range(1,8)).ffill().reset_index()
```

Now If you print `resultdf` you will get:

```
     week      items
0     1        1.0
1     2        2.0
2     3        2.0
3     4        3.0
4     5        4.0
5     6        4.0
6     7        5.0
```

Now If you want items values in `int` then you can make use of `astype()` method:

```
resultdf['items']=resultdf['items'].astype(int)
```