# Add missing dates do datetime column in Pandas using last value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, data-science

I've already checked out [Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe), but I don't want to fill in the new dates with a generic value.

My dataframe looks more or less like this:

| date (dd/mm/yyyy) | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | a |
| 02/01/2000 | b |
| 03/01/2000 | c |
| 06/01/2000 | d |

So in this example, days 04/01/2000 and 05/01/2000 are missing. What I want to do is to insert them before the 6th, with a value of *c*, the last value before the missing days. So the "correct" df should look like:

| date (dd/mm/yyyy) | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | a |
| 02/01/2000 | b |
| 03/01/2000 | c |
| 04/01/2000 | c |
| 05/01/2000 | c |
| 06/01/2000 | d |

There are multiple instances of missing dates, and it's a large df (~9000 rows).

Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
# If your date format is dayfirst, then use the following code

df['date (dd/mm/yyyy)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date (dd/mm/yyyy)'], dayfirst=True)
out = df.set_index('date (dd/mm/yyyy)').asfreq('D', method='ffill').reset_index()
print(out)
```

Comment: Returned an empty df to me :/

Comment: It should not return an empty df, I tested it before posting it.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tcMmRGTh2Lqi don't know what's wrong. ("data" is Portuguese for "date")

Comment: I didn't notice the note in your field, I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dates are drawn at a regular frequency, you can generate a pd.DateIndex with `date_range`, filter those which are not in your date column, crate a dataframe to concatenate with `nan` in the value column and `fillna` using the back or forward fill method.

```py
# assuming your dataframe is df:

all_dates = pd.date_range(start=df.date.min(), end=df.date.max(), freq='M')
known_dates = set(df.date.to_list()) # set is blazing fast on `in` compared with a list.
unknown_dates = all_dates[~all_dates.isin(known_dates)]
df2 = pd.DateFrame({'date': unknown_dates})
df2['value'] = np.nan
df = pd.concat([df, df2])
df = df.sort_values('value').fillna(method='ffill')
```