# How can I fill in missing dates in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df_counts` that contains the number of events that happen on a given day.
My goal is to fill in all the missing dates, and assign them a count of 0.

```
       date    count
0   2012-03-14  8
1   2012-03-19  1
2   2012-04-07  3
3   2012-04-10  1
4   2012-04-19  5
```

Desired output:

```
       date    count
0   2012-03-14  8
1   2012-03-15  0
2   2012-03-16  0
3   2012-03-17  0
4   2012-03-18  0
5   2012-03-19  0
6   2012-03-20  0
7   2012-03-21  0
8   2012-03-22  0
9   2012-03-23  0
...
```

Links I've read through:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html

https://datatofish.com/pandas-dataframe-to-series/

[Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe)

What I've tried:

```
idx = pd.date_range('2012-03-06', '2022-12-05')
s = df_counts.sequeeze
s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
s = s.reindex(idx, fill_value = 0)
s.head()
```

Output of what I've tried:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sequeeze'
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is `fillna`, you can use it for whole df or single column:

```
df["column"].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `asfreq()` function.

```py
# convert date column to datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# set date columns as index, drop the original index
df = df.set_index("date", drop=True)

# daily freq
df = df.asfreq("D", fill_value=0)
```

Some notes on your code:

- `squeeze()` is a function, not an attribute. Therefore you get an error there.
- You can directly use the `date` column as an index using the `set_index()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):**

```
new_df = df.set_index('date').resample('1D').agg('first').fillna(0)
```

**Output**:

```
'''
date    count
2012-03-14  8.0
2012-03-15  0.0
2012-03-16  0.0
2012-03-17  0.0
2012-03-18  0.0
2012-03-19  1.0
2012-03-20  0.0
2012-03-21  0.0
2012-03-22  0.0
2012-03-23  0.0
2012-03-24  0.0
2012-03-25  0.0
2012-03-26  0.0
2012-03-27  0.0
2012-03-28  0.0
2012-03-29  0.0
2012-03-30  0.0
2012-03-31  0.0
2012-04-01  0.0
2012-04-02  0.0
2012-04-03  0.0
2012-04-04  0.0
2012-04-05  0.0
2012-04-06  0.0
2012-04-07  3.0
2012-04-08  0.0
2012-04-09  0.0
2012-04-10  1.0
2012-04-11  0.0
2012-04-12  0.0
2012-04-13  0.0
2012-04-14  0.0
2012-04-15  0.0
2012-04-16  0.0
2012-04-17  0.0
2012-04-18  0.0
2012-04-19  5.0

'''
```