# How to add rows with missing dates in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with empty dates.
How can I add new rows with absent dates?

```
     dt_object        high   
0    2000-01-03   27.490000   
1    2000-01-04   27.448000   
2    2000-01-05   27.597000  
3    2000-01-06   27.597000   
4    2000-01-07   27.174000  
5    2000-01-10   28.090000 
6    2000-01-11   29.250000  
7    2000-01-12   28.850000
```

Expected output:

```
     dt_object        high   
0    2000-01-03   27.490000   
1    2000-01-04   27.448000   
2    2000-01-05   27.597000  
3    2000-01-06   27.597000   
4    2000-01-07   27.174000
5    2000-01-08   0
6    2000-01-09   0
7    2000-01-10   28.090000 
8    2000-01-11   29.250000  
9    2000-01-12   28.850000
```

I saw this answer

Add missing dates to pandas dataframe
[Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe)

but it doesn't describe my situation.
My dt_object is NOT index.

I need universal decision for any timeframes (15 minutes and hours too)

```
15 minutes:
                dt_object     high   
361980 2023-12-13 00:00:00  90.1216  
361981 2023-12-13 00:15:00  90.1308 
EMPTY
361983 2023-12-13 00:45:00  90.2750 
EMPTY 
361985 2023-12-13 01:15:00  90.3023
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your linked solution with `DatetimeIndex` with [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
df['dt_object'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_object'])

out = df.set_index('dt_object').asfreq('D', fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (out)
   dt_object    high
0 2000-01-03  27.490
1 2000-01-04  27.448
2 2000-01-05  27.597
3 2000-01-06  27.597
4 2000-01-07  27.174
5 2000-01-08   0.000
6 2000-01-09   0.000
7 2000-01-10  28.090
8 2000-01-11  29.250
9 2000-01-12  28.850
```

---

```
out = df.set_index('dt_object').asfreq('15Min', fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (out)
              dt_object   high
0   2000-01-03 00:00:00  27.49
1   2000-01-03 00:15:00   0.00
2   2000-01-03 00:30:00   0.00
3   2000-01-03 00:45:00   0.00
4   2000-01-03 01:00:00   0.00
..                  ...    ...
860 2000-01-11 23:00:00   0.00
861 2000-01-11 23:15:00   0.00
862 2000-01-11 23:30:00   0.00
863 2000-01-11 23:45:00   0.00
864 2000-01-12 00:00:00  28.85

[865 rows x 2 columns]
```