# Fill in missing dates in 2023

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to create rows for missing dates so my df contains all dates in 2023.

I'm trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe), but missing something:

> ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"eventDate":["2023-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-12-10"],
        "col1":[1,2,3], "col2":["a","b","c"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#What I have:
#    eventDate  col1 col2
#   2023-01-01     1    a
#   2023-01-01     2    b
#   2023-12-10     3    c

#What I want:
#     eventDate  col1 col2
#   2023-01-01     1    a
#   2023-01-01     2    b
#   2023-01-02    NaN  NaN
#   2023-01-03    NaN  NaN
#   ...
#   2023-12-10     3    c
#   ...
#   2023-12-31    NaN  NaN

df["eventDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["eventDate"])
df = df.set_index("eventDate")
print(df.index)
#DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-12-10'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='eventDate', freq=None)

idx = pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31')
print(idx.duplicated().any())
#False

df = df.reindex(idx)
#ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

Comment: The `event_date` index on the dataframe is duplicated. You can do an outer merge instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the difference of indexes, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["eventDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["eventDate"])
df = df.set_index("eventDate")

out = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(index=idx.difference(df.index))]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
            col1 col2
2023-01-01   1.0    a
2023-01-01   2.0    b
2023-01-02   NaN  NaN
2023-01-03   NaN  NaN
2023-01-04   NaN  NaN
...          ...  ...
2023-12-10   3.0    c
...          ...  ...
2023-12-27   NaN  NaN
2023-12-28   NaN  NaN
2023-12-29   NaN  NaN
2023-12-30   NaN  NaN
2023-12-31   NaN  NaN

[366 rows x 2 columns]
```